# How to check the CapsLock status in Assembly

Tags: assembly, emu8086, capslock

I tried BIOS Interrupt INT 16h, 02h but it is not supported on Emu8086. Can someone teach me how to get directly Capslock status on memory location 0:0417h or other Assembler which supported BIOS Interrupt 16h 02h
I've tried MASM but it's not going well.
Sorry about my bad English

Comment: Assemblers are not what support BIOS calls or not.  This is up to the BIOS you use and it seems like EMU8086 emulates a BIOS that does not support this call.  Another assembler will not help there.

Comment: Perhaps this assembler source [locktest](https://euroassembler.eu/prowin32/locktest.htm) might help you, it monitors Caps|Num|Scroll lock status in DOS, Windows, emulators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The status of the caps lock key can be found in [bit `40h` of the keyboard status word](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/58-keyboard_shift_status_flags.html) at address `0040:0017`.  To access this bit, first load the BDA segment into a segment register, then access memory using this segment register.  The syntax should be something like:

```
        mov     ax, 40h                 ; load segment into AX
        mov     es, ax                  ; so we can move it into ES
        test    byte ptr es:[17h], 40h  ; is caps-lock depressed?
        jnz     caps_pressed

caps_not_pressed:
        ...

caps_pressed:
        ...
```

Comment: That allows an amusing code-size optimization: `test es:[17h], al`, since the segment is the same as the bitmask.  (BTW, you need a `byte ptr` with an immediate operand.)

Comment: Even more hacky code-size optimization: `mov bx, 40h` / `mov es, bx` / `test es:[bx-40h+17h], bl` to use a `[bx+disp8]` addressing mode (1 extra byte) instead of `[disp16]` (2 extra bytes).  Obviously that's much less intuitive and human-readable, and only works with BX if you want to use both halves of the trick.  The other 16-bit-addressing registers (BP, SI, DI) don't have their low byte usable as a partial register, except in 64-bit mode.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you.  I've tried to keep the code example as easy to understand as possible, so I avoided shenanigans like these.

Comment: Perhaps my first comment was misleading.  I meant: when you have an instruction with an immediate operand (and a memory destination), you need a `byte ptr` on the memory operand.  I can see how it could be misread as implying `byte ptr 40h`, but no, fortunately for our sanity, MASM-style syntax requires (I think) the `size ptr` keyword to be on the memory operand.  That looks about right to me, now.  I think `es:` outside the `[]` is where MASM / TASM syntaxes want a segment override.